# $E[X\log X] - \lambda \log \lambda$ when $X \sim Poisson(\lambda)$ as $\lambda \rightarrow \infty$

Tags: poisson-distribution

I know the answer must be $\frac{1}{2}$, because I have done the numerical simulation and as the parameter of the poisson distribution increases, the quantity gets closer to 0.5.
Can we show this analytically?

Edit: For whoever comes across this in the future, you can solve this by expanding $X \log X$ into its Taylor series around $\lambda$. After some algebra, you can show that
$E[X \log X] - \lambda \log \lambda = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{12\lambda} + \frac{1}{12 \lambda^2} + O(\frac{1}{\lambda^3})$

Using the equation above we now have:
$\lim_{\lambda \rightarrow \infty} \big[ E[X \log X] - \lambda \log \lambda \big] = \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum.

Comment: How did you get this power series in $\lambda^{-1}$ ? It doesn't seem obvious to me at all...

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch did you try the Taylor series expansion of XlogX around $\lambda$?

Comment: @Eaman I don’t know what that means, $X\log(X)$ is a function of $\omega\in\Omega$, not of $\lambda$. If you have a reference solving the original question I would be really interested in how it’s done! 

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch  Taylor series expansion of $X \log(X)$ around $\lambda$ is $\lambda \log(\lambda) + (log(\lambda) + 1)(X - \lambda) + \frac{1}{2\lambda}(X - \lambda)^2 - \frac{1}{6\lambda^2}(X-\lambda)^3 + ... $

Plug this in the expectation. After some algebra, you get the answer. I don't have a reference other than my notes.